# How to set a button tag to an array of arrays entry point

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I need some help. I'm currently learning objective c and I'm trying to do the following:

Add to story board a button(action) textfield & label(checked)
type in a number in the text field press the button=>create o a new row a new button with as many text field as requested previously.(checked)
Store each new button+ it's text fields into an array, then store that array in a new array, rows and columns[0][0] etc style(checked)
Add for each new button I create a tag and use array count method for it to identify my button(checked). I do this because each array looks like this [0]button[1]textfield[2]textfield and so on with only textfields following.

Now here is my code to create my button:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(_x, _y, 100.0, 30.0);
[button setTitle:@"Calculate" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.tag = [_arayOfArays count];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

And this is my method that calls it:

```
-(void)myAction:(UIControl*)sender{


if ([[_arayOfArays objectAtIndex:sender]count] == 4) {

 //here i call another method that calculates the area of a triangle if the button I would press would be in a same array with another 3 text fields 
}
```

Now my problem is that my sender address memory always points to [0][0] or [1][0] and so on depending on what i pressed, and I want it to point to [0] or [1] and so on so I can use the count method.

Can anyone please give me a hint on how I achieve this? Thanks and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean to access the element at index specified by the buttons tag like this:

```
[_arayOfArays objectAtIndex:sender.tag]
```

Comment: You pass the sender instead of sender.tag as the index parameter. The sender variable holds the address of the button object.